# Auto collapse to definitions visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, macros, add-in, outlining

I have been looking high and low for a way to auto collapse to definitions in visual studio 2012 when you open a file.

I found a solution for VS2010 here [Any way to auto collapse to definitions whenever you close a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245492/any-way-to-auto-collapse-to-definitions-whenever-you-close-a-document) but that requires a Macros which has been taken out in VS2012.

Any Solution would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, macros are definitely gone from Visual Studio 2012.

Not exactly what you requested, but the `Ctrl-M, Ctrl-O` keyboard shortcut is fast.

Third party tools like CodeRush! or Resharper may help here.  I know that CodeRush is very customizable.

You can also create your own [Visual Studio Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885119.aspx).  Extensions are more powerful than macros, but have a bit of a learning curve.